# What is the regular expression in Notepad++ which matches 1 to 8 character words?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a very big text file. Every line in this textfile has a one word in it.

How do I search for words which are 1 to 8 characters long?

`[A-Za-z]{1,7}` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions match any part of a line that matches the expression. If you want to limit matching lines to a certain length, you need to indicate the start and end of the line. `^` means start of line, `$` means end of line.

```
^.{1,8}$
```

Should match what you're looking for. In English, it means "from the start of the line, there must be 1 to 8 characters, inclusive, before the end of the line". I used `.` instead of some more restrictive character class in case you wanted to include words like "don't", which aren't strictly alphabetic.